# Can't shutown Apache Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache

Hello there I have some vodoo things happening recently on my computer. I am using xampp by default on my Windows 10 machine as a local development environment but wanted to test some things out so downloaded AppServ. After testing I have deleted the AppServ by uninstall.exe in the root folder of the AppServ. While uninstalling it I realized that Apache Server of AppServ was still running. It still listens to port 0.0.0.0:80 althrough there is no Apache folder exists anymore(?). When I navigate to localhost through my browser it says "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.". I couldn't find any 'httpd' and/or 'apache2' services on my Task Manager Services tab. I tried to restart the computer but it is still same. It starts with the boot and can't shut it down anywhere. And no xampp's Apache is not working. It is not the xampp's Apache I see when I open localhost. When I try to start Apache through xampp it says that the port is blocked.

I tried to run "netstat -anb" in the cmd and can see:
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 LISTENING Can not obtain ownership information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out why was this happening. It was not the AppServ but it was the MSSQL Reporting Services which was using 80 port by default...

Try running "netstat -aon" command on cmd (Run as Administrator). There will be listed all adresses and ports with PID's using them. If the PID 4 (Which is System) is 'LISTENING' to 0.0.0.0:80 and if you have MSSQL Server installed then most probably the MSSQL Server's Report Agent is using the port. Just open MSSQL Server Configuration Manager and stop the Report Agent.